# Signal’s desktop app keeps on crashing when trying to make or receive a call

Tags: 20.04, sound, crash, voip, desktop-apps

I have downloaded and installed the [Signal for Desktop app](https://signal.org/en/download/) via the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center). The current version running on my laptop is `v1.40.1`. (**Update:** The new version `v5.0.0` also does not work.)

When someone tries to call me via Signal, my phone is ringing and my laptop notifies me as well with a ringing sound that someone is trying to call me. I can then decide whether I want to accept the call on my phone or laptop. If I accept it on my phone, everything just works fine. But if I try to accept it on my laptop, I can still hear the ringing sound and the desktop app on my laptop has crashed. The same is true if I try to call someone from my laptop.

A friend of mine does not have any problems with the Signal desktop app because he uses a MacBook. So, on Apple devices, everything seems to work just fine but this is not the case for desktop computers running Linux, I suppose.

Is there a bug in Signal’s desktop app for Linux or might some faulty Ubuntu preferences cause the crash? Does anyone know more about this issue?

Maybe I can provide a [debug log and crash report](https://support.signal.org/hc/en-us/articles/360007318591-Debug-Logs-and-Crash-Reports) if someone here can tell me what to look out for in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try downloading Signal's Desktop app from [here](https://signal.org/download/#)!

It is the official website of Signal.

Comment: Installing it this way did not work and reinstalling the `v5.0.0` version also did not help.

Comment: Ooh in that case you may file an issue in GitHub's `Signal-Desktop` repository [here](https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/issues).

Comment: Ok, maybe I’ll post it there then. Thank you anyway.